# Как защитить MySQL от DDoS атак?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, ddos

Ситуация следующая:
Имеется сайт, защищённый бесплатной подпиской Cloudflare. Вначале предполагалось, что этого должно хватить, чтобы защищаться от небольших DDoS атак.... Сайт ложиться от Dos атаки.

Для ясности, используется фреймворк flask, wsgi-сервер gunicorn и nginx.

Для исследования использовался простой python-скрипт, который посылает GET-запросы на сайт в многопоточном режиме. Было выбрано 500 потоков.

Cloudflare почему-то пропускает эти запросы, не считая их опасными. Хотя скрипт не подменяет заголовков, куки, ip и тд. То есть тупой скрипт, который по одному шаблону посылает тысячи запросов. Видимо бесплатный cloudflare на действительно достойную защиту не способен(

После исследования выяснилось, что самому серверу в принципе всё равно на ~500 запросов в секунду, но вот на стадии проверки авторизации и получения информации о пользователе (стандартная функция, которая выполняется прямо перед загрузкой страницы), MySQL замедляется до минимума, так что другие запросы просто не выполняются за нормальное время.

Чтобы ограничить кол-во поступающих запросов с одного IP я сделал простенькую функцию, которая собирает данные о последних посещениях с данного IP в обычную переменную в классе, минуя Mysql, чтобы отсеять IP до начала работы с БД и блокирует его, если запросов за последние 5 секунд больше предела. Выставил ограничение на 50 запросов с одного IP за 5 секунд (10 запросов в секунду), соответственно, перед тем, как эта функция даёт хорошие результаты, первые 50 запросов успевают протиснуться через фильтр и создают 50 запросов к БД, но как оказалось, MySQL не справляется даже с таким кол-вом одновременных подключений и запросов.

Даже если создать firewall правило у cloudflare, которое полностью запретит для IP доступ к сайту, всё равно первые 50 запросов пройдут и сильно замедлят сайт (как минимум на 1 минуту, больше я не считал).

Вопрос теперь вот в чём: является ли данная проблема производительности проблемой моей архитектуры БД? Либо же MySQL в принципе не способен выполнять 50 тяжёлых (в обычных условиях вся подгтовка перед загрузкой страницы занимает 0.3 секунды) запросов одновременно и нужно думать как уменьшить их количество?

Может предложите другие решения?

P.S Если понадобится, дам подробности об архитектуре проекта.

Comment: 1) [оптимизируйте медленные SQL запросы](https://www.getpagespeed.com/monitoring/mysql/optimize-slow-mysql-queries) 2) настройте FastCGI cache в NGINX в тех частях сайта, где это возможно 3) создайте кэш даных часто-используемых запросов например сохраняя их в Redis, для быстрого доступа

Comment: А как по вашему cloudflare должен догадаться что эти запросы неправильные, если как вы говорите никакие заголовки не подменяются А значит для него она выглядят как самые обычные. Если одиночный запрос работает целых 0.3 секунды это уже само по себе не правильно. не должно быть таких запросов, а тем более на этапе проверки авторизации. Авторизация должна проверяться на базовом уровне без обращения к БД. например удостоверится в валидности куки криптографическими методами. И желательно на этом и остановится и в БД лезть в крайнем случае

Comment: По поводу БД MySQL спокойно пробегается по паре тыс записей в БД за десятки миллисекунд. А у вас запрос работает 300 мс. сколько же там записей он обрабатывает и на чем так нещадно тормозит. на лицо неоптимизированный запрос, отсутствие нужных индексов или еще что то в этом роде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Довольно странно, что у вас не справляется MySQL, так как я почти каждый день сталкиваюсь с серверами, где одновременно 100-150 подключений к MySQL с разных пользователей и к разным БД и это совсем не тормозит. Там базы очень разные, встречаются и по несколько гигабайт, десятки даже есть. Более того, по умолчанию там насколько я помню вообще стоять должно 250 одновременных запросов. То есть даже по умолчанию MySQL должен справляться с таким количеством запросов не морщась.

Для начала вам нужно исследовать, что действительно является тормозом. Если у вас не должно быть одновременных запросов от одного клиента много, настройте nginx так, чтобы он просто не пропускал, допустим, больше 10 запросов от одного IP (подберите под себя конечно). Как минимум вы уже отсечете некоторые проблемы, которые не являются на самом деле атакой, но могут эксплуатироваться злоумышленниками из-за вашей архитектуры.

Затем можно смотреть, что за запросы такие, из-за чего "замерзают" другие запросы. В некоторых случаях проблему решает правильная настройка индексов в проблемных таблицах, это может реально ускорить обработку сложных запросов на порядок. А в некоторых возможно придется оформить кеш, например в Redis, который будет выдавать эти данные не обращаясь каждый раз в MySQL. Redis способен обработать сотни тысяч запросов в секунду, у вас скорее скрипты загнутся :)

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, всем спасибо за ответы. Подытожу

1. Время проверки авторизации и прочих подготовительных действий действительно занимало очень много времени. Я убрал запросы, которые в принципе не влияют на функционал проекта. Время подготовки перед загрузкой страницы уменьшилось с .3 секунд до .005
2. Раньше я не дооценивал индексы в mysql. Некоторые запросы занимали у меня по 0.01-0.5 секунд. Добавив индексы я серьёзно ускорил сайт и сейчас он просто летает
3. Уменьшил лимит запросов с 50 за 5 секунд до 20 за 5 секунд. По сути, клиент на практике не будет делать по 4 запроса в секунду, а если даже это и произойдёт, то ему придётся подождать всего лишь 5 секунд и повторить свой запрос.

В итоге это и от Dos атак защитило, расширило возможности основной системы против ddos (которая основана на поведении пользователей, но до неё дело раньше просто не доходило) и заметно ускорило работу сайта.

Всем ещё раз спасибо!